# Integrate 3rd party API authentication on Firebase

Tags: api, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a question about using a 3rd-party API for authentication.

I would like to use firebase for building an application.
I would like to use data from a 3rd party like strava.

What is the best way to Inegrate the Strava-api with Firebase.

How can I implement Strava-authentication in Firebase?

Comment: Did you get answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Strava API OAuth2 protocol for authentication and the use of a Firebase product like FireBase Authentication are not related..

OAuth2 authentication for Strava is for authenticating against the API EndPoint. This will then get user consent and offers a secure way for accessing their data.. FireBase authentication is a way to authenticate users into your app and is a gateway to products like FireBase Storage or RealTime DataBase. Both can be used in conjunction but are not related in code..